# IPython ipyparallel map_sync ImportError

Tags: python, ipython-parallel

I am new to `ipyparallel` and I want to use this package to implement parallel computing with my machine learning application.

The following are a test on `ipyparallel`, I define a function named `add` on func.py file, and the main function on test.py file.

The func.py's codes are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

def add(*numbers):
    numbers = list(numbers)
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        numbers[i] = n + 1
    return numbers
```

The test.py's codes are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from func import add
from ipyparallel import Client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rc = Client(
        '/home/fit/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json')

    print map(add, [1, 2, 3]
    print rc[0].map_sync(add, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Since you know `map` can run without error, but when run `map_sync`, the command line returns:

```
☁  test  python test.py 
[[2], [3], [4]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print rc[0].map_sync(add, [1, 2, 3, 4])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/view.py", line 353, in map_sync
    return self.map(f,*sequences,**kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/view.py", line 54, in sync_results
    ret = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/view.py", line 618, in map
    return pf.map(*sequences)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/remotefunction.py", line 268, in map
    ret = self(*sequences)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/remotefunction.py", line 75, in sync_view_results
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/remotefunction.py", line 251, in __call__
    return r.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipyparallel/client/asyncresult.py", line 104, in get
    raise self._exception
ipyparallel.error.CompositeError: one or more exceptions from call to method: add
[0:apply]: ImportError: No module named func
```

And if I define the function on the test.py file, `map_sync` can run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

#from func import add
from ipyparallel import Client

def add(*numbers):
    numbers = list(numbers)
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        numbers[i] = n + 1
    return numbers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rc = Client(
        '/home/fit/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json')

    print map(add, [1, 2, 3])

    print rc[0].map_sync(add, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

And the result is:

```
☁  test  python test.py
[[2], [3], [4]]
[[2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

I wonder for `map_sync` how to use the function define in other file? And how to import these functions? Since `from py_file import func` does not work for `map_sync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module needed should be copied(or, you can push or the modules) to `engine machines` and 3-party packages should be installed on `engine machines`, if not, `ImportError` will be occured.

But, when running the program, you should run:

```
$ ipcontroller --ip=client_ip --reuse
```

on `client machine`, and there will be 2 files generated in `/home/user/.ipython/profile_default/security` directory

```
$ ls /home/user/.ipython/profile_default/security 
ipcontroller-client.json  ipcontroller-engine.json
```

So, both `ipcontroller-client.json` and `ipcontroller-engine.json` must be copied to `engine machines` and run

```
$ ipengine --file=/path/to/ipcontroller-engine.json
```

on `engine machines`, so the `parallel computing` environment has been set up.

And next, you can define your `parallel computing` tasks and run your programs.